# Xcode Cloud Workflow Fails to Run Tests

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode-cloud

I'm trying to configure an Xcode Cloud workflow at the moment that will run a test action whenever changes to a branch are pushed.

Here's my Workflow configuration:

[image]

Here are my schemes:

[image]

Whenever I run the Workflow, I keep getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Is the testing working in local? The error seems to point to a misconfigured test target.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to tune the cloud config target that you want to run for your tests.

How does your test - iOS config look like?

Is your scheme public?

Is it part of your repository?

[image: Apple Xcode Cloud config for a test scheme]